# Clone SSD from .img with DD

Tags: linux, dd, ssd, clone

I saved a backup from ssd A to .img file with dd command now I want to know to clone ssd A to ssd B can I do it directly from the .img file something like:

`dd if=/dev/backup.img of=/dev/sdc bs=1 status=progress`

Will this be same as doing:

`dd if/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=1 bs=1 status=progress`

Where Disk A = sdb and Disk B=sdc

I already did

`dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/image.img`

I woud prefer to clone it from the .img file as I dont mess something up or do the opposite, so I want to know are those two methods same 100% results?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result will be the same. Note that you may want to choose a larger block size like `bs=4M` (or larger) to speed up things. And of course you only need to specify the `bs` option once.

Answer (score 0):

> I woud prefer to clone it from the .img file as I dont mess something up
>
> Adam  *New contributor*

the problem with using `dd` to clone is the .img your are creating and then writing out to the new disk is will be bit for bit.  Which is to say if you have a 500gb ssd and only have 10gb of of useful operating system + data on it, your .img will be all 500gb of the *partition* including a bunch of empty space.  And then you would need to write that to an equally sized new partition.

A better method for example is doing a `tar -cf myrootpartition.tar  /` where this will only grab relevant bits off the disk per the file system.  However the devil is in the details, and even doing `dd` like you mentioned it will be with `/etc/fstab` and grub for starters where disk mount is by disk uuid and that will be different between your old and new disk.  So it will fail to boot.  It is the details like this where some [free] disk closing tools such as *aeomi* or *clonezilla* come in handy because they take care of that stuff plus the boot loader and all the other little things that will bite you.

fwiw: if your old ssd is linux something like centos 7.x and you want to start using a new ssd in your computer, my experience has been to download the latest version (Centos 7.9 for example) and put to dvd or usb and do a clean install on the new ssd.  This will be a guaranteed working system and clean, versus migrating problems from your old operating system and whatnot.  A clean install from dvd or usb can take less than an hour, the same time which a `dd` of an entire disk or partition would likely take anyway (of likely grabbing a bunch of empty space).

If it's just data, then I recommend using `tar` like I described above to grab just actual data off the file system, and not doing a bit for bit copy of an entire disk partition that may be less than 10% full.

Comment: You wrote: "However the devil is in the details, and even doing dd ...disk uuid and that will be different between your old and new disk." I just cloned my root partition using "dd" and the UUIDs did *not* change, which is what I expected. I think your statement about UUIDs changing applies to copying with "tar" or the like, only.

Comment: the new disk is different so **all** references to disk on the old image being cloned to needs to change to reflect the new disk.  Doing dd or tar will not do that.  if that's not what i wrote this is what I meant.

Comment: one way to get around this, sort of, is having the disk as **mount by-name** with is referenced as `dev/sda#` or `/dev/sdb#` and so on.  The trick is to have your original disk the only disk in the system so it is *guaranteed* to be `/dev/sda`.  Then that will work fine on the new disk provided the new disk is also the one and only disk in the system so it will show up as sd**a**.  This was easy under the ELILO boot loader, which is no longer.  I don't know how to do this in grub2, i don't think grub2 uses mount by name.